# How to set permission/role to specific resource with Shiro

Tags: permissions, roles, shiro, vert.x

I try to implement file server where users has permission to serve/upload to only authorized directory. Here just about what I want in code:

```
    router.get("/files/*").handler(ctx -> {

        String requestedDir = ctx.request().path().replaceFirst("/files/", "");

        ctx.user().isAuthorised("read:" + requestedDir, isAuth -> {
            if (isAuth.succeeded()) ctx.next();
            else ctx.fail(401);
        });
    });

    router.get("/files/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setDirectoryListing(true));

    router.post("/upload").handler(ctx -> {
        String toDir = ctx.pathParam("dir");
        ctx.user().isAuthorised("write:" + toDir, isAuth -> {
          //upload
        });
    });
```

I try to use Apache Shiro, but don't understand how implement this with permission/role. What I want, for example: user1 can serve all dirs, others - only specific dirs.

Theoretical code:

```
user.user1 = pass,write:* // write = write+read
user.user2 = pass,write:/some/folder1 
user.user3 = pass,write:/some/folder2,read:/some/folder3
```

How to implement this with Shiro or maybe another solution?